# How to embed audio into a Jekyll blog?

Tags: audio, jekyll, wav

I am writing a blog under Jekyll.

I would like to embed a simple audio player into one of my posts, in order to allow the reader to play a short .wav file.

Following [these instructions](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/open-embed/), I downloaded the **open-embed.html** file, saved it under my **_includes** folder and modified my **default.html** layout document as suggested.

Now that I have performed the aforementioned steps and saved my audio file to **assets/audio/**, how can I play it from my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of `.mp3` in `open-embed.html` with `.wav`. Or include the following JavaScript function before the closing `</script>` tag, in case you might want to use `.mp3` files in the future.

```
    function wav_embed() {
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        if (p[i].innerHTML.indexOf('.wav') !== -1) {
            var str = p[i].innerHTML.split('?');
            if (str.length == 1) str[1] = '';
            var str1 = str[1];
            str1 = str1.replace('&', '').replace('&', '');
            str1 = str1.replace('autoplay=1', '').replace('autoplay=0', '');
            str1 = str1.replace('loop=1', '').replace('loop=0', '');
            str1 = str1.replace('controls=0', '').replace('controls=1', '');

            if (
                str[0].lastIndexOf('.wav', str[0].length - 4) === str[0].length - 4 &&
                str1.length == 0
            ) {
                if (str[1].indexOf('autoplay=1') !== -1) var autoplay = 1;
                else var autoplay = 0;
                if (str[1].indexOf('loop=1') !== -1) var loop = 1;
                else var loop = 0;
                if (str[1].indexOf('controls=0') !== -1) var controls = 0;
                else var controls = 1;
                var newInnerHTML = '<audio';
                if (autoplay == 1) newInnerHTML += ' autoplay';
                if (loop == 1) newInnerHTML += ' loop';
                if (controls == 1) newInnerHTML += ' controls';
                newInnerHTML +=
                    '><source src="' +
                    str[0] +
                    '" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>';
                p[i].innerHTML = newInnerHTML;
            }
        }
    }
}
wav_embed();
```

Remember to include `{% include open-embed.html %}` either in the post template or at the end of the specific post file (If including an audio file is rare for you, it might speed building up, I don't know).

In the post markdown file, link to the file you want to play like so (Must be as a separate paragraph):

```
Some text.

../../assets/audio/file.wav

Some more text.
```

I'm not sure why I had to go two directories back to access assets because I don't have to do that with my included images. If you have any issues then use the web browser developer tools to check if resources are being found on the network.

Comment: This totally hits the spot! Thanks for your detailed answer, bailey! I had no clue that I just needed to specify the file's path into the post markdown file in order to play it.

Comment: And btw, going just one directory up did the trick for me.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend using `open-embed.html` for achieving a simple task like embedding audio.

Just giving a different approach to achieve the same task.

You can easily create your own partial as

```
# _include/embed-audio.html
<audio controls>
  <source src="{{ include.src }}" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

# Use in the post as
{% include embed-audio.html src="/assets/audio/<audio-source-name>.wav" %}
```

Comment: This does not work inside a markdown list - any idea how to fix that?